# Is "find oneself into" = "share" a particular approach?

Tags: phrase-meaning, translation

I am trying to translate the french idioms: "se retrouver dans cette approche" which I would literally translate to "To find oneself into this approach" but I am not sure if it's the correct way to saying it.

The idea I am trying to convey is not that I fully agree with a particular approach but that my way of thinking is pretty similar to that approach.

There is something in the French idiom that takes into account life experiences that had pushed you to get a pretty similar way of looking at things.

context:

1. the approach is a psychological current
2. I have to use it in a text for a personal description so this isn't a dialogue (I can't use any sentence with "you/your")

Thanks for your help

Comment: It might help to say a little more about what the "approach" is specifically. Is it intellectual knowledge, making something, or ???

Comment: In the senetence I am looking for "approach" is used for a psychological current, but it could be a philosophical current, a scientific one or even a religious one

Comment: "I have a great deal of sympathy with X's approach"

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> I **pretty much/mostly** agree with your approach, but ...

-EDIT-

or

> I **pretty much/mostly** agree with that approach, but ...

Comment: Thanks for this, but I forgot to mention that this isn't a dialogue, so I can't use "your". I have to use it in a text for a personal description.

Comment: Then how about using "that"?

Comment: Thanks @user3169 for coming back here. It's better, but I don't want to put the focus on my disagreement. Also I find that "mostly agree with" doesn't take much "into account the life experiences that had pushed my to get a pretty similar way of looking at things". Any other idea?

Comment: How about "Based on my experience(s) I basically agree with that approach, but ..."?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an idiom, like *I see where you're coming from*. Other appropriate idioms include: *I get what you mean* or *we're on the same page*.

These indicate generalized agreement but leave room for *but...*

Comment: Thanks for this, but I forgot to mention that this isn't a dialogue, so I can't use "you". I have to use it in a text for a personal description.

Answer (score 1):

```
 I find myself (largely|mostly) in agreement with...
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with explanation, examples, and backing from authoritative sources.

Comment: I am an authoritative source.  Accurate answers may not deserve upvotes, but they do not deserve downvotes merely because they don't provide examples or additional explanation.

Comment: Downvotes signal that the answer is *incorrect*. Lack of upvotes can signal that it is not as complete as it might have been.